# RVest trying to scrape date time field

Tags: rvest

I am new here as well as with web scraping. I am trying to figure out how to get the date/time from a piece of html code. I would think this is quite simple with Rvest, but it is taking me a while already. My best guess was:

test <- page %>% html_nodes("span") %>% html_attr("time")

But it returns all "NA".

Thank you for your advice!

```html
<div class="v-popover"><span aria-describedby="popover_1chdwnsl8d" class="trigger" style="display: inline-block;"><time datetime="2019-03-30T04:55:56.000Z" title="Saturday, March 30, 2019, 05:55:56 AM" class="review-date--tooltip-target">Mar 30, 2019</time> <div class="tooltip-container-2"></div> <!----></span> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the url and expected output please?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rvest)
pg <- read_html(<path>)
datetime <- pg %>% html_node(xpath = "//time") %>% html_attr("datetime")
date <- pg %>% html_node(xpath = "//time") %>% html_text()
datetime_long <- pg %>% html_node(xpath = "//time") %>% html_attr("title")
```

This will return the result in the text. You might want to convert to date or datetime type.